# Example code from Javascript textbook giving unexpected error

Tags: javascript

Preface - not relevant to problem
First off I am a noob to Javascript and am in the process of learning it. I have read a lot of Eloquent Javascript but towards the end found it to be too advanced for my level. I was recommended to start reading Professional Javascript for Web Developers by Nicholas Zakas.

Problem
Now I'm attempting to just try and run ObjectTypeExample04.htm which I've included here:

```
function displayInfo(args) {
    var output = “”;
    if (typeof args.name == “string”){
        output += “Name: “ + args.name + “\n”;
    }
    if (typeof args.age == “number”) {
        output += “Age: “ + args.age + “\n”;
    }
    alert(output);
}

displayInfo({
    name: “Nicholas”,
    age: 29
});

displayInfo({
    name: “Greg”
});
```

From what I can understand, it'll just print the object defined in the call to displayInfo and it'll do this through appending the output variable inside that function.

I don't get why I'm getting this error

> Exception: SyntaxError: illegal character

when running it in a JavaScript code runner (don't know the technical name). But basically I tried using JSFiddle to no luck and I don't understand what's wrong because I copied and pasted it out of a textbook.

Comment: Probably those weird quotes... Try changing “ to "

Comment: Thanks a lot guys that was the issue - should just write the thing out rather than copy and paste ...

Answer (score 5):

Replace the “ ” symbols with standard " quotes and try it again.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm) (`“`) and [RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm) (`”`) where you should be using [QUOTATION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/index.htm) (`"`) (or [APOSTROPHE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27/index.htm) (`'`)).

This is typically caused by writing code using a word processor which automatically replaces straight quotes with typographic quotes instead of a regular text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "smart quotes" by regular double quotes:

```
function displayInfo(args) {
  var output = "";
  if (typeof args.name == "string"){
    output += "Name: " + args.name + "\n";
  }
  if (typeof args.age == "number") {
    output += "Age: " + args.age + "\n";
  }
  alert(output);
}
displayInfo({
  name: "Nicholas",
  age: 29
});
displayInfo({
  name: "Greg"
});
```